# map as div background - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm using for a while following javascript code to load google map as DIV background.

```
// When the window has finished loading create our google map below
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

            function init() {
                // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                var mapOptions = {
                    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                    zoom: 15,

                    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.549047, 18.443433), // New York

                    // How you would like to style the map. 
                    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                    styles: [   {       featureType:"all",      elementType:"all",      stylers:[       {           invert_lightness:true       },      {           saturation:10       },      {           lightness:30        },      {           gamma:0.5       },      {           hue:"#1C705B"       }       ]   }   ]
                };


                // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
            }
```

works perfectly. But when I've tried to load there a marker which will point to my location, it crashes. Any ideas what will be the proper placement of such? I assume this is the proper code (which doesn't work..):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.549047, 18.443433);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Please define "crashes"

Comment: it means that the map is not loading.